# spring data jpa issue with postgres - Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

quoteEntitiesPage = quoteRepository.findAllByQuoteIds(quoteIds, pageRequest);

The above query gives me the error "Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value" if the count of quoteIds parameter is above Short.MAX_VALUE.

What is the best approach to get all quote entities here? My Quote class has id(long) and quoteId(UUID) fields.

Answer (score 7):

When using a query of the type "*select ... where x in (list)*", such as yours, Spring adds a bind parameter for each list element. PostgreSQL limits the number of  bind parameters in a query to Short.MAX_VALUE bind, so when the list is longer than that, you get that exception.

A simple solution for this problem would be to partition the list in blocks, query for each one of them, and combine the results.

Something like this, using Guava:

```
List<QuoteEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Long>> partitionedQuoteIds = Lists.partition(quoteIds, 10000);
for (List<Long> partitionQuoteIds: partitionedQuoteIds) {
  result.addAll(quoteRepository.findAllByQuoteIds(partitionQuoteIds))
}
```

This is very wasteful when paginating, but it might be enough for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL driver **42.4.0** you can now pass up to 65,535 records to IN operator.

> fix: queries with up to 65535 (inclusive) parameters are supported now (previous limit was 32767) PR #2525, [Issue #1311](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1311#issuecomment-1143805011)

Source: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/changelogs/2022-06-09-42.4.0-release/